# Connecting WCF Service with a SQL -CLR Stored procedure via a Class Library - SQL-CLR throwing error

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, stored-procedures, sqlclr

I am trying to build a prototype , where WCF Service is hosted in a windows console application and a class library ( DLL) is talking to access the service from the WCF , which is called as a reference from A SQL CLR Stored Procedure.

I referred the following article from MSDN

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Calling-WCF-Service-from-a-8071ceaa#content

Listing out the components..

1. My WCF Service - which is running perfectly
2. ClassLibrary which calls the service - or the service client
3. SQL-CLR Stored procedure

My SQL-CLR Stored Procedure class is showing issues here...
I have succesfully registered the Assemblies in the SQL-CLR Stored procedure in visual studio, but when the whole system works together, I am getting the following error....

```
     public static void spCallWcfService (string name)
{
    {
        try
        {

            SqlPipe sqlPipe = SqlContext.Pipe;
            string new_name = String.Format(name);
            string result = MyClassLibrary1.MyClass.TestFunc(new_name);
            SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Call Succesful");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SqlContext.Pipe.Send(ex.Message);
            //SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Connection works, but there is error!");
        }
    }
```

My call to spCallWcfService  is succesful, but my connection to the Class Library, which talks to the Service is throwing me the following Error.

The error code is as follows.
"The settings property 'MyClassLibrary1_svcService_Service1' was not found"

My First Error code during the initial connect , pushed to the SQL Pipe is as follows.

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure callWcfTest, Line 0
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "callWcfTest": 
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.String MyClassLibrary1.MyClass.TestFunc(System.String)'.
System.MissingMethodException: 
   at StoredProcedures.spCallWcfService(String name)
```

MyClass Library code is as follows, which consumes the Web Service

```
    public static string CallWcfService(string name)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        using (Service1 client = new Service1())
        {
            result = client.SayHello(name);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

My Doubts are as follows:

1. What is the issue between the ClassLibrary and CLR Library, I think,
   I have referenced the DLL's correctly and the build was succeeded in
   Visual studio with no errors.
2. Is the reference to the ClassLibrary done correctly in the SQL CLR
   Stored Procedure

**Kindly  help, I am stuck!**